# little bug with showDiv function js

Tags: javascript, function

I need some help for a small bug with javascript. i'm a noob with js so i don't know how to do ...

I'd like to show different contents on the same page by clicking on different buttons.
I've used the showDiv() function but all the butons use the same function so thats not working and i don't know how to attribute a function to each.

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/pjberot/pen/RyOJBO

```js
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('txt1').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('nxt1').style.display = "inline";
}

function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('txt2').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('nxt2').style.display = "inline";
}

function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('txt3').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('nxt3').style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" name="answer" value="BOUTON 1" onclick="showDiv()" class="btninfo" /><div id="txt1"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list slideDown" >
<br>
Le texte 1 ici
</div>
<div class="nxt" id="nxt1" style="display:none;"> NEXT (1) </div> 

<input type="button" name="answer" value="BOUTON 2" onclick="showDiv()" class="btninfo" /><div id="txt2"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list slideDown" >
<br>
Le texte 2 ici
</div>
<div class="nxt" id="nxt2" style="display:none;"> NEXT (2) </div> 

<input type="button" name="answer" value="BOUTON 3" onclick="showDiv()" class="btninfo" /><div id="txt3"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list slideDown" >
<br>
Le texte 3 ici
</div>
<div class="nxt" id="nxt3" style="display:none;"> NEXT (3) </div>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: pass a parameter to you `showDiv(parameter)` and then inside the function check the value of the parameter and call it respective code.

Comment: Just name them differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare multiple functions with the same name, you overwrite the previous declaration with the new one. So when you declare `showDiv` three times, only the last one works :)

The simplest (albeit not the cleanest) way to do this would be to give your functions different names:

```js
function showDiv1() {
document.getElementById('txt1').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('nxt1').style.display = "inline";
}

function showDiv2() {
document.getElementById('txt2').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('nxt2').style.display = "inline";
}

function showDiv3() {
document.getElementById('txt3').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('nxt3').style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" name="answer" value="BOUTON 1" onclick="showDiv1()" class="btninfo" /><div id="txt1"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list slideDown" >
<br>
Le texte 1 ici
</div>
<div class="nxt" id="nxt1" style="display:none;"> NEXT (1) </div> 

<input type="button" name="answer" value="BOUTON 2" onclick="showDiv2()" class="btninfo" /><div id="txt2"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list slideDown" >
<br>
Le texte 2 ici
</div>
<div class="nxt" id="nxt2" style="display:none;"> NEXT (2) </div> 

<input type="button" name="answer" value="BOUTON 3" onclick="showDiv3()" class="btninfo" /><div id="txt3"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list slideDown" >
<br>
Le texte 3 ici
</div>
<div class="nxt" id="nxt3" style="display:none;"> NEXT (3) </div>
```

As the functions are very similar in nature, you could perhaps make it a little more concise by using function arguments

```js
function showDiv(blockId, inlineId) {
document.getElementById(blockId).style.display = "block";
document.getElementById(inlineId).style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" name="answer" value="BOUTON 1" onclick="showDiv('txt1','nxt1')" class="btninfo" /><div id="txt1"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list slideDown" >
<br>
Le texte 1 ici
</div>
<div class="nxt" id="nxt1" style="display:none;"> NEXT (1) </div> 

<input type="button" name="answer" value="BOUTON 2" onclick="showDiv('txt2','nxt2')" class="btninfo" /><div id="txt2"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list slideDown" >
<br>
Le texte 2 ici
</div>
<div class="nxt" id="nxt2" style="display:none;"> NEXT (2) </div> 

<input type="button" name="answer" value="BOUTON 3" onclick="showDiv('txt3','nxt3')" class="btninfo" /><div id="txt3"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list slideDown" >
<br>
Le texte 3 ici
</div>
<div class="nxt" id="nxt3" style="display:none;"> NEXT (3) </div>
```

There are other better way of handling events (like click) in Javascript.. I'd recommend reading the [Introduction to Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) page on MDN to get a good overview of this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chirag for your answer and your other suggestion! I've used the onclick function that is smarter and works perfectely !!!
Many thanks for your support!